# can i install plugin with old kotlin version to newer project

Tags: flutter-dependencies

What went wrong:
The Android Gradle plugin supports only kotlin-android-extensions Gradle plugin version 1.6.20 and higher.
The following dependencies do not satisfy the required version:
root project 'android' -> org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.5.31